# Can someone please ID this succulent

Tags: identification, houseplants, succulents, cactus, tropical

Can someone please ID the succulent seen in the image below:

[image]

Comment: which one?  You have two in there, a burrowtail sedum and another

Comment: @kevinsky i cropped the photo so that its more clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think its Pachyphytum oviferum, also known as Moonstone or Sugar Almond plant

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pachyphytum_oviferum